# WaitCommEvent WINAPI Serial Port Event

Tags: c, winapi

I have been refering to the following page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx to create event driven serial port. In my initialisation I set the following:

```
Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams); 
Status = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams); 
Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);
```

In my WinMain I then use WaitCommEvent to listen for the data to be recieved on the port. It looks like the following:

```
while(1){
    if( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else{
        //SetWindowText(hStatic, "");
        Status = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, NULL); //Wait for the character to be received
        if (Status == TRUE){
            ReadFromSerialPort();
        }
    }
  }
```

This works fine, all the data is being read exactly as it is coming in and I can press a write to port button and the data is written and other stuff so no real complaints. However the code is basically glorified polling, constantlty checking the status of WaitCommEvent and reading the port when true. I would rather not poll at all and just sit there until an event happens, like an Interrupt Service Routing used in microcontrollers. Is this possible using win32?

Thanks.

Comment: [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx).

Comment: ^^ that, or thread off the serial comms.  I guess, in the end, it comes down to how much GUI interaction there is between your serial comms and the GUI, and how much work is done by the serial interface.